# Android - Show/Set a Layout at Specific Location

Tags: android, view, android-activity, android-layout

In my application I want to set a Layout at a specific location. Let me explain. When I touched on activity (at any location), a view (or layout example:`LinearLayout`) will show(Popup like) at the touched position.

Any suggestion?

```
________________
|              |
|              |
|     _____    |
|     |   |    |
|     |   |    |
|     -----    |
|              |
|              |
|              |
----------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use this custom dialogue & u can edit it also click the below link
http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: Great. Looking exactly for this. Thanks for helping. :)